# Can you make a bonus-action to throw a dagger from Two-Weapon Fighting before you take your action?

Tags: dnd-5e, two-weapon-fighting

So I have non-thrown one-handed-weapon in my main hand and light melee weapon with thrown property in my second hand. Can I throw my weapon in second hand before making a attack with my main hand?

> Two-Weapon Fighting (Combat Rules) When you take the Attack action and attack with a light melee weapon that you’re holding in one hand, you can use a bonus action to attack with a different light melee weapon that you’re holding in the other hand. You don’t add your ability modifier to the damage of the bonus attack, unless that modifier is negative. If either weapon has the thrown property, you can throw the weapon, instead of making a melee attack with it.

Comment: Hello BlackburnUTG and welcome to RPG.stackexchange! Kindly take the [tour] and enjoy your stay!

Comment: We've marked your question as a dupe because it has been asked before. This isn't a bad thing as this question might help others find that one. If that question doesn't answer it for you, please clarify for us how and why and we'll we what needs to be done to help you.

Comment: While the actual question has been answered in the duplicate, you might want to consider asking about the balance implications of allowing what you want, because it is thematically sound, and closer to how people fight in real life.

Comment: Actually, the PHB includes the text, "If either weapon has the thrown property, you can throw the weapon, instead of making a melee attack with it." Since it says "either weapon" can be thrown, you should be able to throw the thrown weapon as your main attack and attack with the melee weapon as your bonus, so either order should be valid.